# Nuget not including mscorlib.dll

Tags: nuget, nuspec

Nuget ignores adding references to a project when the DLL is named **mscorlib.dll**. Any way force nuget to add a references to the project, or copy the DLL to the bin output directory?

Here's the snippet from the .nuspec file:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\..\bin\mscorlib.dll" target="lib\net45" />
</files>
```

The necessity is for deploying an alternative implementation of mscorlib.